# Emit role's permissions as claims in JWT with AAD (Azure AD)

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt

I need to emit a role's permissions as claims in the JWT.

The aim is to get a certain user's permissions as claims in the JWT for authorization purposes.

The user belongs to a group which is assocciated to a certain role which has certain permissions in the Azure Active Directory.

Clarification:
If I add some items to the appRoles array in the app's manifest, the role names are emitted as role-type claims in the JWT in the following format:
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: [value property in the appRole item as appears int he manifest appRoles array]

But I couldn't find any way to emit role's permissions' names (or any other property) as claims.

I've been googling and digging in MS docs for days but couldn't find anything. I hope that it's possible.

If it isn't possible, a clumsy workaround may be to represent the permission we need to be emitted as an AAD role, and to represent the role (in the meaning of "a set of permissions") as an AAD special group, and then to associate the groups we wanted to be associated with the role (in an ideal world) to that special "role"-group.

But it's very clumsy as we will actually lose the natural meaning of role which is a set of permissions, and the natural meaning of group which is a set of users and/or groups

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

The value property is the custom role name you configured and will be returned in JWT. It's by design.

**The permission name won't be returned in the JWT**. After you have added an appRole into the Azure AD app, you need to [assign users and groups to the role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-roles).

You need to add the needed permissions in Azure AD APP and then control the permissions in your code.

We assume you have assigned a custom role in an Azure AD app and added a user to this role.

When a user signs in, a token which includes the role claim will be returned. You can judge the user's role in the code. If it matches a custom appRole, he is allowed to perform an operation. If the user does not match any of the appRoles, he does not have permission to perform any operations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've already achieved all of what you wrote and it's working. I'm asking specifically as emphasized in the question's title as well as in its body - is there a way to emit the permissions themselves that are associated with that custom role as claims in the jwt so that I could make a real claims-based-auth rather than role-based-auth?

Comment: If you just want to know what permission a user has, you can assign only one permission to each role. And set the value property the same as the permission name.

Comment: That's exactly the clumsy workaround that I described in the quesiton (with a little expansion) which makes the role lose its purpose as a "set of permissions" (just like a group is a "set of users and/or other groups"). And while the groups ObjectIds may be emitted (with a limit of a certain number in order to not make the JWT too huge, in which case we should only call the Graph API to fetch all the groups) - I didn't see any way to emit the permissions as claims. And calling the Graph API is an expensive roundtrip that I'm trying to avoid of course o.w I wouldn't have asked the question

Comment: Again, I'm looking for claims-based-authorization rather than role-based-authorization just as its possible with identity server. If I would write an auth server myself I would provide an option to emit the user's direct permissions (e.g from UserClaims table if using Identity) as well as all the permissions that are associated with all the roles that are associated with all the groups that the user is a member of (from RoleClaims joint with the user's roles and the user's groups' roles) and thus get all the permissions that the user has, either directly or indirectly